# Bad oscilloscope probe does not measure DC

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, repair, probe

I seem to have messed up my oscilloscope probe during PCB testing. Too high a voltage was applied and there was arcing between the probe and a pin on the PCB. The probe can still read square waves very well (using the compensation terminals on the oscilloscope and a 115V square wave on the PCB.) The problem arises when i try to read a DC voltage.

When trying to measure the switching on of a 115VDC output, I get a signal that rises up to 115V, then slowly comes back down to 0. (The DC source keeps on outputting 115V,1A so the output is definitely active).
[image: 115VDC switch on waveform]

Also, when measuring a 12VDC supply, i get the following sinusoidal waveform.[image]

I have opened up the probe and the resistors and capacitors seem fine (no broken chips and no heat traces). I am looking to understand what is happening with the probe and repair it if possible.

The probe model is the RP3500A passive probe from RIGOL.

PS: I have measured the previous waveforms with another probe using the same oscilloscope channel and i get a clean switching on of 115VDC and a constant 12VDC.

Thank you!

Comment: Your DC supply shows 60Hz - have you got the ground connected?

Comment: Did you try measuring the resistance between both ends of your probe?

Comment: The channel seems to be ok because when measuring with another probe, using the same channel, the signals are good.

Comment: I am measuring 8.9Mohms between both ends.

Comment: If it's a x10 probe then 8.9MOhms seems okay (due to the 1MOhm input impedance) of the channel. Your meter is high enough impedance to measure 8.9MOhms properly, right?

Comment: @Keving White,

You seem to have put me on a good track. The ground probe was connected but there is infinite resistance between the ground probe and the ground plating at the other end of the probe. I am guessing the wires are open somewhere along the way. Thanks!

Comment: After a re-check, the ground wire was in open circuit.

Comment: Could your scope be in AC coupling?

Comment: The ground clip wires of scope probes can easily break and your symptoms match a broken ground wire.